# Why doesn't tcpdump catch packet after specifying ip?

Tags: tcpdump

when I use`tcpdump -i eth0 -nn`,you can see the packet from 192.168.19.101
(I don't have enough reputation to post a picture)
but when I specify ip,tpye`tcpdump -i eth0 -nn host 192.168.19.101`,tcpdump captured no packets but recieved some packets.

WHY?

Comment: What happens if you try `tcpdump -i eth0 -nn vlan and host 192.168.19.101`?

Comment: yes,it works.I forget to tell that i catch packets on a port mirroring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, then it's an unfortunate consequence of the difficulty of handling VLAN encapsulation in BPF.  VLAN packets captured on a "raw" interface (that supplies packets with their VLAN headers intact) aren't treated as IP packets, they're treated as VLAN packets, so you need to do "vlan and" to skip past the VLAN header.

Comment: You're totally right! Now I think of modifying the original unpack algorithm to support VLAN packets.